# Will moving transformer to separate case reduce noise in opamp-based circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transformer, noise

I'm building a simple phono preamp for my friend. I've designed a transformer based power supply to be on the same board as an opamp, then I hesitated - will I get less mains interference if I move the transformer and linear regulators to separate box that will be far away from the preamp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find magnetic shielding foil designed specifically for transformers. It's a bit expensive though! You can try to build a shielding enclosure for the power supply. It needs a high [µ constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_%28electromagnetism%29#Values_for_some_common_materials). Although the price of mu metal is ridiculously high, you can substitute it with steel and still get some shielding. You can even take a shortcut and use an existing shielding cage from a scrap power supply lying around somewhere.

Also, depending on the construction of the transformer you're using, the magnetic field escaping outside of its core might not be that strong. Sure, you could move it a few feet from your amplifier, but that might not be necessary. It would actually be a good experiment to test how much noise your transformer induces in traces around it.

Comment: You may also find that orienting the transformer differently can reduce interference.  The leakage from transformers isn't uniform, so the interference is directional.  If you've ever seen a transformer mounted diagonally, now you know why.

Comment: You reminded me - [this little java applet lets you play with magnetic fields to see how they work](http://www.falstad.com/emwave2/). Among the setups, there is a transformer

Answer (score 5):

You'll have little interference *inside* the opamp, but maybe some in traces leading to it. More in longer traces, higher impedances, and lower voltages. Keeping the transformer away from the very low voltage input signal (especially for moving-coil) is a good idea. You may want to buy a transformer in a μ-metal casing, or build such a casing for it yourself.